# Triggering div click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically appedning a div.

```
$('#parent').append('<div id="sub"></div>');
```

How can I trigger a click event on this DIV when an image (`#go`) is clicked?

html

```
<img id="go" src="img.png" />
<div id="parent"></div>
```

js

```
$('#go').on('click',function(){
     //console.log("test1");
     $("#sub").click();
});
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Have you hooked an event handler to `#sub`? It will have to be attached after the element has been appended to the DOM, unless you're using fancy event delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work... Added a handler to verify...

```js
$('#parent').append('<div id="sub"></div>')
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  $("#sub").click();
})

$('body').on('click', '#sub', function(e) {
  console.log('sub clicked')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="go" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPE0C.jpg?s=48&g=1" />
<div id="parent"></div>
```

**Note: Clicking `#sub` also triggers the event**

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger method  `$("#sub").trigger('click');`
The trigger() method triggers the specified event and the default behaviour of an event (like form submission) for the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trigger()`

```
$('#go').on('click',function(){
     $('#parent').find("#sub").trigger('click');
});
```

, make sure the click event for `#sub` is delegated

```
$('#parent').on('click','#sub',function(){
//some code here
});
```

Comment: Since `#sub` is being referenced as an ID, there's no need to use `.find()`. You can just use `$('#sub')`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

use event.preventDefault() first and then trigger click:
`$('#go').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#sub").click();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Sure you just to bind a click function to the `#sub` div.
Check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/NahushF/69e4zy3o/1/) fiddle